# Increase vote limit for moderators

Tags: feature-request, voting, moderators

Being an active moderator on SharePoint.SE I find myself stuck with the limit of 30 votes a day. When I'm active I can spend hours on the site trying to make it more useful and interesting, which for one thing is to show appreciation by voting.

On our site there are a lot of fly-byes who come in new, drop a question, get a perfectly good answer, but no votes. Not accepted answer, nor upvotes. To overcome this issue I've tried to read through all the "unanswered questions" queue which adds up to 30 percent scoring more than 10'000 at the moment.

Another issue specific to us is that we work on a server product where we in our daily work life are consulting on customer servers in search for info, but unwilling to sign on on *.SE because it's the customer server. We still need the info, but are restricted to sign-in with our own accounts.

Because of this I want to extend moderator daily voting limit from 30 to at least 50 to make the work of our community more worth while (through reputation).

Would this be possible to implement?

Comment: You have 40 votes, not 30, as long as at least 10 of the first 30 are on questions. I don't understand why moderators should have more votes than other users. It's good that you strive to vote a lot, but this is not in any way a moderator prerogative.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Why wouldn't you be able to log in? You can use private session in your browser, right? I think people might be too lazy to vote, and that is a problem you are not going to fix by giving mods more votes.

Comment: I agree with @Gilles here; I don't think this is something we should have, as moderators. Our job is not to judge the 'technical' accuracy of answers, so I don't think we should be given any extra ability in that department.

Comment: @Gilles I agree that voting isn't the primary task of a moderator. But in our specific case, we have issues how users access the site and why they are there. Other SE sites are more interest related or not doing work through a remote session. This is the main difference, and the real reason for me to posting this feature request.

Comment: @PatrickHofman The luxury of having an account of you own is rare in the consulting industry of SharePoint. You often get access through a shared account such as domain\admin with the password DonotChange54. Your session can be ripped of at any second from another consultant or maintainance management somewhere in India. I'm reluctant to log in with my google account under these circumstances. It's hard enough to sign in on your OneDrive to download the latest custom package. This is a real issue on server consultancy.

Comment: @BennySkogberg: I wouldn't call it a luxury. I have been working with several banks and other large companies as consultant, but I wouldn't take them serious if they gave me another persons account. But that is off topic for here I think.

Comment: @Andrew'saUnitato Tecnical inaccuracy I leave to the community. I deal with comments posted as answers due to low rep below 15, spammers and link only answers. If answers or questions are technically wrong usually solves itself on SP.SE

Comment: @PatrickHofman I totally agree on that. But since intranet and document management via SharePoint isn't as business critical as an ERP, then this is my fellow colleagues reality. Bad? Yes! Serious? Well, yes, since you can't follow who did what. Scary? Hell yeah! :)

Comment: @BennySkogberg: I guess they work from a terminal anyways then, so why not log in there?

Comment: @PatrickHofman and a faul proxy as well, and we're home free, right? But we still can't use our google accounts on the server.

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion, you shouldn't workaround a problem with a solution like this. The actual problem is that the ones who find the post useful, don't vote, since you say there are on a central server.

In my opinion, that is just lazy. There are plenty other ways to log in if you really want to. But I think actually they don't want to (just like 99% of the googlers around on StackOverflow, to give an example).

If you give moderators more votes, you say, *they* should determine the usefulness of a post rather than the *ones who actually find it useful*. I think that is a bad idea.

Comment: [Are SharePoint.SE users lazy voters?](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/853/are-sharepoint-se-users-lazy-voters)

Comment: No. I said the general population of SE is (I compared SP.SE to SO)

Comment: It's a link to our meta. Sorry for not explaining that mor clear.

Comment: @BennySkogberg [Yes, they are](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/1094).

Comment: I don't see the logic of it being a *bad* idea for mods to be able to help decide which questions are "good" questions.  It's not like they can vote multiple times for the same question/answer.  If high-rep users, or even *just* moderators, could vote 80 or 100 times per day I think you'd see even more engagement from those people.  And after all, they have been elected *by the community* and are thus trusted to make decisions about which questions are good.  I think the limit should be flexible based on the number of questions the site receives per day vs the number of actively voting users.