# Moderator activity limits (voting, reviewing, etc.)

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderator-abilities, limits

I'm curious about something. Do moderators have limits for various actions like normal users? In particular

- Voting (normal users have 40 votes)
- Reviews (20/40 per queue for normal users)
- Asking questions (I believe a normal user ask at most 50 per day)
- Answering questions (not sure about limits here)
- Comment voting
- Mod flag handling

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) - A majority of actions in this list note caveats for moderators, if they exist.

Comment: As for moderator flag handling, there is no limit. You can review as many moderator flags as is possible without losing your sanity :)

Comment: Wow @Spevacus, that's really cool, and it answers all my questions but the one that was my primary motive for asking this question: Do mods have unlimited Q/A votes?

Comment: It would seem like they need that, because if you're going to review a lot of posts, you'll want to vote on them...

Comment: To my knowledge, moderators still have an upvote limit like normal users. I'll try and find a post that says that verbatim, though.

Comment: Per [Increase vote limit for moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236751/increase-vote-limit-for-moderators), mods have the same amount of votes as regular users.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I'd say you're right. Although it seems dumb, because reviews and voting often go hand-in-hand.